# Inquiry on MS GRAPH APIs and its effect on VSTO Addins

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I currently have a VSTO Outlook addin which uses the interop libraries to read/send/delete emails.

Will these interop libraries be affected by Microsoft's move to stop support on November 2022, for REST APIs and enforce the use of GRAPH APIs instead?

This may be a stupid question, but I have not read any conclusive documentation that interop libraries will be unaffected by such change.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific, what is the "end of support" you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your VSTO addin won't be affected: Outlook does not use REST API. It does use MAPI, MAPI-over-HTTP, EWS, and Graph internally, but none of that (except MAPI) is directly exposed through the Outlook Object Model and VSTO API built on top of it.